# AWS DataPipeline Dependencies not yet created

Tags: amazon-web-services

Datapipeline in AWS without any issues till week. From today, its showing as "Dependencies Not Yet Created" error when trying to create EC2 instance for running shell script. Anybody's help is much appreciated.

Pipeline has two preconditions and one shellscriptactivity. Two preconditions are getting passed, issue is with creating the resource for executing the shell script.

It is not creating the EC2 instance with the given AMI and stays in Waiting on Dependencies state. I have exported pipeline and created a new pipeline with it. New pipeline works fine and not sure why the old pipeline is not working.

Any guesses? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... Could you show up the error? Did you make any change since last week?

Comment: Pipeline has two preconditions and one shellscriptactivity. Two preconditions are getting passed, issue is with creating the resource for executing the shell script. It is not creating the EC2 instance with the given AMI and stays in Waiting on Dependencies state. I have exported pipeline and created a new pipeline with it. New pipeline works fine and not sure why the old pipeline is not working :( Any guesses?

Comment: Add the information in your post, not in a comment, please...

Comment: Added the additional info in post. Any solutions?